# Create composite index in AppEngine + Firestore in Native Mode

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

We are currently developing an AppEngine Standard application using Cloud Firestore in Native Mode which is working very well.
Now, we want to support a query that needs a composite index which we try to create using a `index.yaml` file:

```
indexes:
  - kind: myentity
    properties:
      - name: owner
        direction: asc
      - name: created_at
        direction: asc
```

When testing this with `gcloud app deploy index.yaml`, we observe that indexes are being created. However, the created indexes are Cloud Datastore indexes not Cloud Firestore ones, even though Datastore is "not even enabled" (The Cloud console wants to send you directly to Firestore view if you try to access the Datastore view).
Therefore, our queries are failing.
How do we instruct AppEngine to create Firestore indexes not Datastore indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For composite indexes in Firestore (native mode) you can use the [gcloud cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/indexes/composite/create) or the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/indexes/composite).

If you would like to check in your indexes into a configuration file, you can also use [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/firestore_index).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you are saying is true, however, I was hoping that there is a smart solution in place that does not ruin the ease of deploying an app engine application. I really like the idea of having these yaml solutions that you deploy with your Application source and that set up several stuff.

Comment: I think, I have to  partially revert my previous comment, since the CLI does not provide the possibility (at least not documented) to create a composite index for a "Collection" query scope:


 This must be specified.

       --collection-group=COLLECTION_GROUP

Comment: Composite queries are collection scoped by default in Firestore native mode.  To get collection group scoped queries you need to use --query-scope=COLLECTION_GROUP when creating the indexes.